# checking for email address in mysql db

Tags: php, database, mysqli

So im trying to do what should seem and probably is a very simple mundane task. I am trying to check for an email address in my db. I dont know if im on the right track or not, can some one straiten me out please?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 68_users WHERE email= $email";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query) == $email) {
     echo 'Email has been registered';
}else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO 68_users (email,pass,old_pass,first_name,last_name,dob,gender,phone,fanmail) 
             VALUES ('$email',AES_ENCRYPT('$pass', 'something'),AES_ENCRYPT('$pass', 'something'),'$first_name','$last_name','$dob','$gender','$phone','$fanmail')" 
             or die(mysqli_error());
    if ( !mysqli_query($link, $query) ) {
        echo 'error: '.mysqli_error($link);
        exit();
    }
}
mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Thank you all for your help. I need to figure out a debugging situation for php. Right now i write in eclipse and debug on my site, very aggravating.. this is what i used:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 68_users WHERE email= '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo 'This email has previously been registered';
}else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO 68_users (email,pass,old_pass,first_name,last_name,dob,gender,phone,fanmail)
    VALUES ('$email',AES_ENCRYPT('$pass', 'something'),AES_ENCRYPT('$pass', 'something'),'$first_name','$last_name','$dob','$gender','$phone','$fanmail')"
    or die(mysqli_error());
    if ( !mysqli_query($link, $query) ) {
        echo 'error: '.mysqli_error($link);
        exit();
    }
    header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/html/thankyou.html' ) ;
}
```

Comment: If you run it, what happens?

Comment: `WHERE email= $email` at least needs to be `WHERE email='$email'`, you shouldn't use `AES_ENCRYPT` for passwords as it's reversible, and I'm guessing you're vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Use prepared statements in here - will make your life much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query will fail as you need apostrophes around the email variable. also you can simply run the query and see how many rows are return:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 68_users WHERE email= '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo 'Email has been registered';
}else{
 // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `quotes` around the variable `$email`,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 68_users WHERE email= '$email'";
```

You will need to see the result of the rest of the code, to know if everything else works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the results of your current code, the one problem I can spot is that you want to make sure you enclose the email value in single-quotes for your query statement to ensure that it is evaluated properly:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 68_users WHERE email='$email'";
```

Omitting the quotes will result in an error when your query executes, which depending on your verbose handling, may or may not be visibly apparent.  As a further point, this would be where basic debugging comes into play, which is a fundamental for all programmers.

Remove the equality check for your email, as your query statement is already doing that for you.  If there aren't any rows returned, then it will return false and trigger the else statement:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 68_users WHERE email='$email'";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    // Registered
}else{
    // Not Registered
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 68_users WHERE email= '$email'";
```

will also return a array of values, your "if ($result ... == $email)" will fail.

*var_dump($result)* to see whats coming back from the query.